# Jekyll tables using arrays

Tags: html, arrays, html-table, jekyll

I need to put multiple sets of data into one array.

This is my google.yml file located in _data/google.yml

```
teams:
  - rank: 1 
    name: awsomebot 
    qp: 2 
    rp: 123 
    plays: 5

  - rank: 2 
    name: coolbot 
    qp: 1 
    rp: 56 
    plays: 5
```

This is my main file (google.md)

```
 ---
layout: pastTournaments
title: Google Tournament
permalink: /tournaments/google/
---

<div class="colum-wrapper">
    <div class="grid-x">
        <div class="large-6 small-12 cell">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th width="20" class="centered">Rank</th>
                    <th width="300" class="centered">Team</th>
                    <th class="centered">QP</th>
                    <th width="50" class="centered">RP</th>
                    <th width="50" class="centered">Plays</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for team in site.data.teams %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ team.rank }}</td>
                            <td>{{ team.name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ team.qp }}</td>
                            <td>{{ team.rp }}</td>
                            <td>{{ team.plays }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor%}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="large-6 small-12 cell">
            <h2 class="centered">4998 Berean</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my code (I use foundation 6), it is in google.md and it produces this:

[image: https://ibb.co/nhZjcw]

I want it to do this:

[image: https://ibb.co/b3uZcw]

I plan to have 16 teams which should match with this:

http://www.norcalftc.org/eventResults/2017/Google_Qualifier/Rankings_Google_Qualifier.html

and I plan to use the same type of table for other tournaments

I have updated it, but I can't get the data and md files to display.

Comment: UPDATE: I have added my _data/google.yml file into my main folder, and attempted to link the two files together

Comment: You've edited your question in a way that makes my answer meaningless. I delete it. Correct syntax is `{{ site.data.google.teams }}'

Comment: nope your answered help me alot, so did this one, thank you